# why the mountpoint in container can't been seen in host

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, filesystems

I want do some device initiation by using Daemonset(K8s resource).

Actually the deivce has been formated(inside container) and mounted(inside container) successfully to a container path `/hostmnt/lvpmem/` which is mapped of `/mnt/` which is a host path.

`mountpoint` works fine in container

```
[root@driver-hm4ll /]
#mountpoint /hostmnt/lvpmem/
/hostmnt/lvpmem/ is a mountpoint
```

but `mountpoint` works wrong in host env

```
[root@host ~]# mountpoint  /mnt/lvpmem/
/mnt/lvpmem/ is not a mountpoint
```

Also the data I write in container under `/hostmnt/lvpmem/` can't been seen under `/mnt/lvpmem/` in host env.

How can I mount the device so that both host and container can see it ?
Also, if container is destroyed does the mount relation also be destroyed ? I have no idea about umounting the device in host env if mount relation can't be seen.
Some opensource project use `nsenter` in container to run such format/mount command does it help ?

Comment: If this is in Kubernetes, I wouldn't expect you to be able to "format a device inside a container", nor would I expect you to be able to log in to the host.  What's your higher-level goal with this setup?  Rather than showing the shell diagnostic commands, can you edit the question to include a [mcve] showing how you're creating this filesystem?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have a special block device which is unformated. The user pod need read/write the path mounting this device by using `spec.hostPath`. Before pod using this block device,  I want the bolck device can be initiated in Kubernetes automatically not manually so I use the daemonset  to do `mkfs` and `mount` to create this filesystem.

Comment: What should happen if one of the DaemonSet pods gets deleted?  This sounds like something you'd want to set up when you were provisioning the worker node and not from inside a pod (and it sounds like a "how do I set up my node" question and not a "how do I write my application" question).

Answer (score 1):

- add /mnt as a volume to pod on directory /hostmnt. So that whatever being written under /hostmnt  directory (insisde the container) will be seen on host under directory /mnt .

```
Example of a pod with hostpath :

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /hostmnt
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /mnt
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```

Comment: my confusion is after I mounted a device to /hostmnt such  /hostmnt/devmp/,  data written under /hostmnt/devmp/ can't be seen on host under  /host/devmp/.

Comment: As far as i know that is not possible .. I do not see any option where container & host can use same ```mnt namespace``` which is required to achieve your requirement

Comment: After I restart the container `mountpoint /hostmnt/devmp/` returns `is a mountpoint` and the data written under `/hostmnt/devmp/` can be seen on host `/mnt/devmp/` . I supposed the key answer is about how `hostPath` works.

Answer (score 0):

Mount point seen in container is just the snapshot when container start. My solution:

1. Enable hostPID for pod and use `nsenter` to mount on host
2. Restart container itself by using `exit` then the mount point can be seen in new container